# Where does the tagline "The saga is now complete" appear?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

I distinctly remember the tagline of "The saga is now complete" being used for *Revenge of the Sith*. I've also heard other people mention this. However, I am unable to find any posters or covers that use it.

Was this actually the official tagline? And if so, where was it used?

Comment: THEY LIED TO US!

Comment: @WadCheber well the "rise and fall of Darth Vader" saga that Lucas set out to tell is complete. **So what they told us was true... from a certain point of view!**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe you're conflating Vader's quote

> the circle is now complete

with the movie trailer for *Revenge of the Sith* which mentions

> the saga is complete

and the tagline for the *Complete Saga* boxset

It can be noted, however, that the official DVD description for [Revenge of the Sith](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000AOTUA2) *does* mention a very similar quote, but this was not a quote widely advertised as a full marketing tagline.

> **The Star Wars saga is now complete** on DVD with Episode III REVENGE OF THE SITH. Torn between loyalty to his mentor, Obi-Wan Kenobi, and the seductive powers of the Sith, Anakin Skywalker ultimately turns his back on the Jedi, thus completing his journey to the dark side and his transformation into Darth Vader. Experience the breathtaking scope of the final chapter in spectacular clarity and relive all the epic battles including the final climactic lightsaber duel between Anakin and Obi-Wan.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure about "The saga is **now** complete", but the [official *Revenge of the Sith* trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5UnjrG_N8hU) ends with the similar "the saga is complete":

[image]

This is also the tagline listed on [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0121766/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1).

I can only find one quasi-official use of the phrase "the saga is now complete"; it was reportedly the title of [an article in *Star Wars Insider 86*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Saga_is_Now_Complete), but I can't personally confirm this.